# AWS ElasticBean Deployment: @prisma/client did not initialize yet. Please run "prisma generate" and try to import it again

Tags: amazon-web-services, nestjs, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, prisma

### Project Configuration

- **Framework**: NestJS
- **ORM**: Prisma
- **Deployment platform**: AWS Elastic Beanstalk

### Issue

When deploying my NestJS application using Prisma ORM to AWS Elastic Beanstalk, I encounter an error stating `@prisma/client did not initialize yet. Please run "prisma generate" and try to import it again.`

### What I Have Tried

1. Followed the instructions given in the [Caveats when deploying to AWS platforms](https://www.prisma.io/docs/guides/deployment/deployment-guides/caveats-when-deploying-to-aws-platforms#aws-elastic-beanstalk).
2. Added the Prisma CLI package to project dependencies instead of devDependencies, and ran `npm install` to update the `package-lock.json`.
3. Set the AWS Elastic Beanstalk `NPM_USE_PRODUCTION` environment property to `false` to install devDependencies on AWS Elastic Beanstalk instances.

Despite these steps, the issue persists.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.